# How to automatically restart Jelastic containers killed by OOM killer

Tags: jelastic

I have Docker image which have issues with memory leaking. It's known issue for this specific tool and authors recommend to restart nodes from time to time as a workaround.

However, daily restart is not always enough and some processed are killed by Jelastic OOM killer. I wan't not to kill them, but completely restart. If I've had real Docker running on a machine I would be able to instruct it to restart container after OOM or something like this, but in Jelastic I don't have such option.

Simple solution would be to add supervisord or something like this to my setup and take care about it but I'm wondering is there some out-of-the-box solution from Jelastic for this.

Comment: Have you tried CloudScripting already? It's possible to do with help of the event onAlert https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/events/#onalert - you can subscribe on the event and call action restartContainers https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/actions/#restartcontainers

Comment: Nope, didn't know about it but from first look it's far easier to add supervisord or other babysitting solution to my setup...

Comment: yep, supervisor is a simple way to go, you can adjust it according to specifics of your application